# openldap in bash - get group member's by sAMAccountName?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have been using a command similar to the following to query for group membership:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://999.999.999.99\
-LLL -D \
"CN=BindCN,OU=Group,OU=Functional,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" \
-x -w password \
-b "OU=GroupName,OU=Shares,DC=domain,DC=com" \
"cn=groupCN" \
-s sub member
```

This will list all members of the group by DN:

```
member;range=0-1499: CN=Last\, First (F),OU=Employees,OU=Users
 ,DC=domain,DC=com
member;range=0-1499: CN=Last\, First (F),OU=Employees,OU=Users
 ,DC=domain,DC=com
member;range=0-1499: CN=Last\, First (F),OU=Employees,OU=Users
 ,DC=domain,DC=com
...
```

Which is alright, but say that I have a list of sAMAccountName's that is 5000 lines, and I want to see if any are in the above group (which has 5000 members.) Is there any way for me to query group members by sAMAccountName?

Comment: Not from one LDAP Query. You would have to query the samAccountNames and get the DNs and coordinate them to the member DNs. -jim

Comment: I suppose that solution is alright. Thanks for the info. Is a DN guaranteed to be unique, though? If two CN's are identical, and they exist in the same OU's, then wouldn't the two DN's be identical as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the DN in LDAP is always unique. It is not possible for the RDN (CN) to be the same within the same container.

The DN is the Fully Distinguished Name (ie CN=somecn,OU=Employees,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com)

You will need to query for the samAccountName(s) which will return the DNs and then resolve the group members from the DNs.

-jim